# convert doc to html by php script

Tags: php

In the last few hours I found script for php which converts a `.doc` file to a `.html` file but I've not been successful yet.

I just made some simple code for it, like this:

```
<?php 

    header("Content-type: application/html");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=as.html");
    echo $content = readfile('abc.doc');

?>
```

It makes an output like the one shown below in the image.

[image]

any other way to do this ? as same to same as `.doc` file  ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already search for a solution? I just found this link, perhaps it might help you:
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/130342/convert-.doc-to-html-or-txt-on-fly-during-upload-with-php